# UIAlertView button opens a new view, but the navigation and tool bars are missing

Tags: xcode, navigation, tableview, uialertview

I have set up a table view. In the main view, I've used an alert message: if user clicks OK button, then the table view will open.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        myTableViewController *nextViewController = [[myTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The table view does get displayed, but some parts are missing. There is a navigation bar on the top and a tool bar in the bottom which are gone missing. Only the cells are displayed.

When I transit to this table view from other approach, it can be displayed properly, so I don't know what went wrong.

Anyone can help please? Thank you!

Comment: You should push and not present the view controller if you want to keep a navigationController stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are presenting the view, then you need to create the `UINavigationController`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        myTableViewController *nextViewController = [[myTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        /* BEGIN NEW CODE */
        /* Here, you will init the navController with your table controller as the root, this is important. */
        UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];
        [controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
        [controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        /* END NEW CODE */

        /* You will now present "controller" instead of the table controller */
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I'll also note that you need to create a "Dismiss" button *(or however you plan to dismiss this navController)* in your `myTableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you! That really works! Just two things though: One is the title of the Navigation bar doesn't show. Two is how do I get the bottom tool bar to be displayed as well?

Comment: You need to set the title in your nextViewController. You also need to create any toolbars since (in the code) you aren't loading any nibs. I assume you have an XIB that contain a toolbar? If so, just load that XIB in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling presentViewController which does not push it to the navigation stack, but rather shows it modally on top of the current view. You want to call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very good to know. But my current view doesn't have a navigation controller. Only the next view does. What should I do then? Thanks again in advance!